# interrupt oracle query with Oracle data access client

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, data-access, oracle-manageddataaccess

I want to kill oracle query after 10 mins of its execution through c#, I achieve it by using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.dll, but my existing project is using System.Data.OracleClient.dll in which `cmd.CommandTimeout` is not updating on runtime [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYWIS.png). I searched alot but couldn't find anything, Its not logical to switch to new dll on which whole project is relying. Is there anything that can be done to update/set `CommandTimeout` in System.Data.OracleClient.dll.
Below code is with System.Data.OracleClient;

```
string connString = "Data Source=xx; User ID=xx; Password=xx;";
var conn = new OracleConnection(connString);
var cmd1 = new OracleCommand(cmdString1, conn);
                  
cmd1.CommandTimeout = 6;

conn.Open();

try
{
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
        
}
```

cmd1.CommandTimeout remains 0 even after code execution. Below is with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

```
string connString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=xxx); User Id=xx; Password=xx;";
                           
conn = new OracleConnection(connString);
var cmd1 = new OracleCommand(cmdString1, conn);
cmd1.CommandTimeout = 6;

conn.Open();

try
{
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
}
```

this code is killing the query but I cant use this dll.

Comment: Is it possible for you to utilize the ExecuteNonQueryAsync method, which is the async version of ExecuteNonQuery?

Comment: Not sure about the CommandTimeout, but ExecuteNonQueryAsync takes a cancellation token, where you could pass in a token that cancels after 10 minutes. Might solve your problem?

Comment: @JacobShanley can you provide me any example related to it.

Comment: Something like this:                 

var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
await cmd1.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(cts.Token);

Comment: Let me know if that works, I can post it as an answer. I just haven't been able to personally test to see if it solves your problem.